“Salam, I dont know if I’m muslim, is this shirk and is this sin?”
This is not about me but my someone that I knew from before, we were young then and he said something like would do some thing even if it meant angering Allah. I am curious, was this a sin, to be okay and not wish but want to anger Allah.

This question is similar to: What is shirk in Islam?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Also try to clarify your question as much as you can, rather than saying he said something, just say the thing so there is no ambiguity.

As mentioned in the previous comment, an earlier question has answered what shirk is, but if you are angering Allah, while not associating partners with Him, it's more of just 'sin' than 'shirk', but either way, it should be avoided. You gain nothing from angering the Lord of all worlds.
